# Encryption of file using algorithm Salsa20

Tags: c#, file, encryption, byte

I'm doing my homework. It's connected with encryption of file.
I use algorithm Salsa20
Here's my code:

```
using (var salsa = new Salsa20.Salsa20())
            {
                using (var fstream_out = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Write))
                {
                    salsa.Key = key;
                    salsa.IV = iv;
                    using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(fstream_out, salsa.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                        cstream.Write(bytes, 0, 1000000);
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I try to encrypt file, there's exception "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
What's wrong?

Comment: Firs see which [process](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) assuming using windows if Linux use `lsof`. And better if you mentions the OS for this cause.

Comment: I just created it and only when I'm trying to encrypt it, there's such exception
I use Windows 8.1

Comment: Please first see the blocker than it will be more clear to answer.

Comment: There's no blocker. As I said, I can edit file but when I'm trying to encrypt it, there's exception. I think problem is in FileMode

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mnlvwq

Comment: reboot and try again?

Comment: Try disabling protection measures (virus scanner) **temporarily** when the problem doesn't go away. The most likely issue is however that there is a lost debug process out there that's keeping the file handle. Try another file name and see what happens. FS errors aren't always on topic; make sure your path is correct and try writing a file yourself in the directory you're targeting.